# IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 127. error: [blank]

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have been attempting to use `pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf`, but when I use it, I get the following error:

```
"IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero **code** **127**. error:"

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 119, in to_pdf
    raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr.decode("utf-8")))
IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 127. error:
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running wkhtmltopdf manually like this:

`wget google.com
wkhtmltopdf index.html out.pdf`

In my case, I didn't have wkhtmltopdf installed. I had to do:

`sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`